# Install WordPress blog along with laravel website

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, laravel

I have a website written in PHP and Laravel 4 framework deployed on Apache web server. In Laravel, I moved the files from the 'public' folder to the root folder so that users can see the website using the main website address (e.g. `example.com`, not `example.com/public`).

Now, I want to deploy a Wordpress blog on the /blog path (e.g. `example.com/blog`) along with the main website. I was wondering how can I point that address to the Wordpress blog while every url of the website is controlled by Laravel routes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a blog folder on your public directory . unzip a wordprees installer in blog folder . Now if you hit the url example.com/blog then you can see the wordpress installer . Then configure your blog.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. When I hit example.com/blog, Laravel routes will handle that and it's not going to show me the wordpress blog!

Answer (score 0):

Follow @Avijit Das answer and then 
Add this line in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)
```

Now it will look something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond $1 !^(blog) 

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: It does not help and has no effect